# The type or namespace name 'Utility' does not exist in the namespace 'Aspose.Cells' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

Heyyy.. I'm facing a pickle at the moment.

I need to develop a program and one of it many functions is that it could convert JSON files into CSV files..

Here's what I have :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using Aspose;
using Aspose.Cells;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\cpi\log\V510ResultsInfo\cpi001.json");

            Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();

            Aspose.Cells.Cells cells = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells;

            Aspose.Cells.Utility.JsonLayoutOptions importOptions = new 
            Aspose.Cells.Utility.JsonLayoutOptions();
            importOptions.ConvertNumericOrDate = true;
            importOptions.ArrayAsTable = true;
            importOptions.IgnoreArrayTitle = true;
            importOptions.IgnoreObjectTitle = true;
            Aspose.Cells.Utility.JsonUtility.ImportData(str, cells, 0, 0, importOptions);

            workbook.Save(@"C:\cpi\log\V510ResultsInfo\convertedjson.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is **'Utility'** in **'Aspose.Cells.Utility'** .. Been breaking my head searching online but it seems that there's nothing much going on about this..

All I know is that 'Aspose.Cells.Utility.JsonLayoutOptions' is in the 'Aspose.Cells.Utility' namespace which falls in the Aspose.Cells.dll.. There's nothing wrong with the DLL everything is great.. Just that the error is still there :

Error Message : **The type or namespace name 'Utility' does not exist in the namespace 'Aspose.Cells' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 1):

adding to the provided answer of jayrag I would like to say, that Apsose.Cells.Utility seems to be a newer namespace and therefore it's not available for older versions of Aspose. I just checked it for the version 17 and there it is definitely not available. I also couldn't find any alternative method inside Aspose.Cells which could help you. It simply seems that the json support is still quite new and to use it you would need to upgrade the license. In the light of the prices for aspose you should probably go with a work-around. Hope that helps a bit.
Cheers!

Comment: That's what I thought and that's why I can;t seem to find anything.. Haizz thanks anyway <3

Comment: Yes, import JSON to Excel and export Excel to JSON are newer features, so you got to upgrade to and use newer version of Aspose.Cells to execute your code segment.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need Aspose for create csv
Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\cpi\log\V510ResultsInfo\cpi001.json");
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    InsertRecordInCsv(model, "convertedjson");
}

public static void InsertRecordInCsv<T>(T model, string fileName)
{
    string targetFolder = @"C:\cpi\log\V510ResultsInfo\";//fileSaveFolderName
    if (!Directory.Exists(targetFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
    }
    string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName + ".csv");
    if (!File.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create);
        fs.Close();
        string csvHeader = string.Empty;
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            csvHeader += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvHeader) ? "," : string.Empty) + info.Name;
        }
        csvHeader += Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(targetPath, csvHeader);               
    }

    StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();
    string csvModel = string.Empty;
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        string value = GetPropValue(model, info.Name) != null ? GetPropValue(model, info.Name).ToString() : string.Empty;
        sbData.Append("\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\",");
    }
    sbData.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, sbData.Length - 1, 1);

    File.AppendAllText(targetPath, sbData.ToString());
}
 public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
 {
   if (src.GetType().GetProperty(propName) != null)
       return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
   return new object();
 }
```

Comment: Hey Man! 1st of all thanks for getting back to me so quickly.. I wasn't surprise that the code can be executed! And when I press the button, it creates a CSV file.. But the problem is there is no data in the CSV file :(

Comment: Okay I know what's wrong..
It's :
sbData.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, sbData.Length - 1, 1);

But I have no idea why tho..

Comment: are you created `Common.GetPropValue()` function ?

Comment: I did..         public string Name
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }

Comment: just updated Answers check added `GetPropValue()` function